# Domain and codomain of this function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have to find the domain and codomain of the function $\ln(\ln(x))$. I don't even have an idea what it looks like. Anyone could help me?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Can you tell us what you have tried? Can you answer the same question regarding $\log(x)$? Also, for the answer you do not even need to know how the function looks like.

Answer (score 1):

What values can $x$ take on to not cause problems for $\mathrm{ln}$? What about the values $\mathrm{ln}(x)$ can take on so it doesn't cause problems for the outer $\mathrm{ln}$?

Comment: You need to find the largest set of x-values that won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Domain**:

Domain of $\ln(x)$ is $(0,\infty)$
$\implies$ domain of $\ln(\ln(x))$ is $(1,\infty)$

**Range**:

Range of $\ln(\ln(x))$ is same as the range of $\ln(x)$ i.e. $(-\infty,\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\ln(\ln(x))$$

Since the domain of $\ln(x)$ is $(0,\infty)$, then the domain of $f(x)$ is $(\ln(0),\ln(\infty))$ or $(1,\infty)$

Since $f(x)$ is an always increasing function, the range is given as $(\lim_{x\to1}f(x),\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x))$ or $(-\infty,\infty)$